# What aircraft has a single constant orange light?

Tags: aircraft-identification, aircraft-external-lights

I live under a fly path in Oldham near Manchester and I see planes passing by every day/night as they approach the airport. However today around 21.20 I have seen something different too.

A plane just passed above our house to start its approach to Manchester then when it was further away roughly above Ashton-under-Lyne I noticed a contrast single orange light passing above the house.

It was somewhat higher than the passenger planes around this area and it's travelled with constant great speed. I followed with my eyes until it's disappeared on the horizon above the peak district (took about 1.5-2 minutes). It's travelled in a direction about SSE (roughly towards London). I couldn't find anything on the Internet suggesting anything flying with constant orange light. BTW it had no sound whatsoever and it wasn't showing up on flight radar either as I checked that straight away. I do not drink and do not smoke funny things. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: How could you tell that it was higher than the passenger planes in the area?

Comment: Judged by my eye. Passenger planes approaching MAN airport flying only 3-4000 ft above. And this could be somewhere around that region too but seemed to be a bit higher than approaching aircrafts in the area.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds more like the International Space Station than an aircraft. That looks like a small orange or yellow light because it's the reflection of the sunlight For that reason you're most likely to see it in the hour or two after sunset, and it's clearly visible with the naked eye in good visibility. It's much higher than aircraft and takes about 90 seconds to travel horizon to horizon. Obviously you won't hear it or see anything on aircraft tracking sites.

That said, ymb1 suggested looking at [this ISS tracker site](http://www.isstracker.com/historical). Assuming your 2120 was in British Summer Time (UTC+1), the ISS would have been somewhere over the South Pacific Ocean at that time, which would rule it out.

Comment: I've seen the ISS passing by quite a few times but that is obviously "flying" way much higher than this blob did.As I just commented on the above for ymb1 (judged by my eye) this thing seemed to be flying just a touch higher than approaching aircrafts for MAN airport. Those approaching in the altitude 3-4000 above us. I also thought it was maybe a drone, but even drones would have flashing lights on and the speed was just very fast and obviously as it disappeared on the horizon remote control would be an issue. (unless it would have its own satellite navigation)